# jQuery .offset setting y value

Tags: jquery, css, offset

I am a newbie to jQuery. Could someone answer this please?

I know I will set layer1 to the position of layer2 with the following line of code.

```
$("#layer1").offset($("#layer2").offset());
```

How can I just set the y-value? I'm not sure about that.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The jQuery documentation for [`.offest()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) reads:

> .offset() returns an object containing the properties top and left.

Knowing this, you can accomplish the following:

```
var offset = $("#layer2").offset();
$("#layer1").css({
    'top' : offset.top,
    'left': offset.left
});
```

Or, you can set them individually, per your requirement.

```
$("#layer1").css('top', offset.top);  // or...
$("#layer1").css('left', offset.left);
```

Finally, since you only need a single value (top), offset is overkill; it's more expensive than you need.  Use the following, optimized snippet instead.

```
var top = $('#layer2').css('top');
$('#layer1').css('top', top);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use/set the css top property

```
$("#layer1").css("top",$("#layer2").css("top"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#layer1").css({
  'top': $("#layer2").offset().top
});
```

**EDIT** .top/.left appears to be setters.
**EDITv2** the offset can be set but must be done through .offset() method.

Answer (score 0):

According to
http://api.jquery.com/offset/

```
$("p:last").offset({ top: 10, left: 30 });
```

can be used. As such you should be able to just remove what you want don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Use offset.top and offset.left - those are the x and y's..  offset() in itself returns both x and y (or top and left)

Comment: For confusion sake, it should be made clear that **top** is **Y** and **left** is **X**. You don't mention them respectively, just wanted to add clarity.